# Browser extension force YouTube videos to get entirely cached

Tags: chrome, youtube

I am looking for a browser extension that can force the YouTube video to get entirely cached upon loading the page (or at worst when I start playing the video). If possible, for Chrome and free.

Comment: See if this works for what you need: [Disable YouTube DASH Playback](http://lifehacker.com/preload-entire-youtube-videos-by-disabling-dash-playbac-1186454034)

Comment: @bobSmith1432 Thanks, seems great. On Chrome the gear icon that's supposed to allow access to YouTube settings doesn't seem to appear if you use the .crx, you need to get the userscript version. But disabling DASH doesn't seem to work :( Works good on Opera though (but add some UI bugs)!

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure if there is an extension for this, but you might be aware of Google Chrome's new HTML5 player which seems to do this and uses this new format on YouTube instead of Flash Player.

I find it really useful (Google Chrome's new format) and some of the benefits I noticed of this was that it pre-loads the YouTube video, even when you pause the YouTube video and also seems to load the entire video too when paused.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question here, but I don't think an extension may be needed for this though. But by default Chrome already uses this format on YouTube. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/html5) too. :)